# Indefinite integral calculation with sine and cosine

Tags: calculus

So I have this problem.

$$\int \frac{\sin^3x}{\cos^5x}dx$$

I initially wanted to use $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$ identity

$$\dfrac{\sin^2x\sin x}{\cos^5x}dx=\dfrac{(1-\cos^2x)\sin x}{\cos^5 x}dx$$ which is then rather trivial to simplify and integrate by using $u$ subsitution $(u = \cos x)$.

However, this solution is not correct. I checked on various websites and they want me to use tan with $\tan^2x + 1 = \sec^2x$. I don't understand why this approach is the correct one.

When I replaced my problem from $\int \dfrac{\sin^3x}{\cos^5x}dx$ to $\int \dfrac{\sin^3x}{\cos^4x}dx$. They use the $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$ identity and not the tan one. Why is this the case?

Why is my approach erroneous for the first problem?

Comment: Because the first reduces simply to $tan^3 x \sec^2 x$ while the second looks like $\tan^3 x\sec x$. The first has the form $u^3\cdot du$ and the second doesn't. Note that you can use whatever way you like, it may just take more computation effort and the results may look different.

Comment: But why would u look for the tan identity in both cases since $sin^2x+cos^2x=1$ can be done directly. Moreover, in both cases where I use this identity, it comes down to the denominator being different from $u^5$ for the 1st problem and $u^4$ for the second problem

Comment: It just becomes easy since $u = \tan x$ gives the value of the first integral as $\frac{\tan^4 x}{4} + C$ directly without any other manipulation. Note that this is only easier. There can be many other convoluted ways of getting to the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac1{2u^2}-\dfrac1{4u^4}=\dfrac{2(1+t^2)-(1+t^2)^2}4=\dfrac{1-t^4}4$$ where $t=\tan x$ which differ with $\dfrac{\tan^4x}4$ by a constant

In general, we can choose $\cos x=u$ for $$\int\sin^mx\cos^{2n+1}x\ dx$$ where $n$ is an integer

Comment: how did u go from $1/2u^2$ to the next equation

Comment: @John, $$u=\cos x,t^2+1=\dfrac1{u^2}$$

Comment: Where does the $t^2$ come from? Sorry still confused

Comment: @John, for the ease of typing, I've replaced $\tan^2x=t$

Comment: How do you mange to get to $(1+t^4)/4$

Comment: It should be $\frac{-t^4+1}{4}$